# Is there a way to use a variable for an operator?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to use a variable in place of an operator? Such as:

```
char additionSign = '+';
int number = 1;
int number2 = 1;

Console.WriteLine(number additionSign number1);
```

I know this code won't work, but is there a way to do this another way?

Comment: Put the operation in a Func? `Func<int, int, int> op = (int a, int b) => a + b; int result = op(11, 22); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exact syntax does not work, no.

But you can make a delegate taking two `int`s and returning and `int`, for which you could pass any lambda.

```cs
Func<int, int, int> oper;
oper = (a, b) => a + b;   // addition lambda
oper = (a, b) => a - b;   // subtraction lambda
oper = (a, b) => a * b;   // multiply lambda

Console.WriteLine(oper(number, number1));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this ... you can add different operator if you wants

```
var operator = {
    '*': function(a, b) { return a * b },
    '<': function(a, b) { return a < b },
     // ...
};

var op = '*';
alert(operator[op](10, 20));
```

Comment: That's not C# code, but the principle is the same I suppose

Comment: More JS than C# I think

Comment: In C# `var @operator = new Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, dynamic>> { ['+'] = (x, y) => x + y, ['<'] = (x, y) => x < y };`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Using dynamic has a non-zero cost (it has to spin up the DLR at runtime and essentially compile the code and track the call sites). May as well return object in that case and pattern match or direct cast on the result. Definitely not something I'd suggest to someone new enough to the language that they have to ask such a question

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I'm well aware of that, but sometimes the cost is actually negligible in the grand scheme of things. Especially true since the runtime optimizes successive invocations. Irrespective of all that, it was the closest translation of the JavaScript code in my opinion. Although I do like the idea of returning an object in using pattern matching

Comment: @AluanHaddad I entirely fail to see why you would return `dynamic` when you can return `int` so you could just declare it `new Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, int>>`

Comment: @Charlieface one the functions in the JavaScript above returns a Boolean result, `<`.

Comment: OK so why not `new Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, object>>`? You simply don't need the extra cost and complexity of `dynamic` unless you intend to do late-bound calls

Comment: That's an option but I was attempting to approximate the JavaScript above.

Answer (score -1):

You're fundamentally changing the syntax of the C# language. You're introducing the idea of a binary operator alias. Interesting, I won't ask why you want to do that. Instead, I will say that you probably want to look into a DSL or [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) transpiler engine. In the same way that languages like TypeScript [transpile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpile) to JavaScript, you could make a language that would compile to C#. The language you're talking about could alias anything it wanted to.